# PATH, removing old versions from usr/bin

Tags: command-line, dependencies, libraries, perl

I'm new to Ubuntu. I inherited a computer from another person. She installed many small programs for bioinformatics in the root folder and `/usr/local/bin`.

I need to be able to remove the old versions because they either interfere with the new version, or, even if I try to run the newer version using the whole path to their command, and/or include the path in PATH, still the old version will be used.

I have trouble accessing these folders so that I can delete files. Or would deleting individual files even just make the problems worse? 
Most of these tools are not found through the Software Center or `apt-get`.

Anything I can do besides formatting the whole drive and starting from scratch?

I also have similar trouble with shared libraries for perl, bioperl, python, you name it. They can't be found, they can't be updated etc.
I know this is not truly an Ubuntu question, so even a redirect to better source for answers would be appreciated (books or websites).

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to avoid reinstallation. Do you need the software you're talking about, or some other things on the system?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove installed programs on /root folder I recommend you just to delete any subfolder related to those apps. For example, if you have a program called 'biolis' installed in /root/biolis, just do:

```
sudo rm -r /root/biolis
```

I just checked my own Ubuntu installation and in the /usr/local/bin folder I only have manually install programs, so you can use the same step above.

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/biolis2
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like yours, it is often easiest and fastest to install a fresh version of Ubuntu or Ubuntu community flavour (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu).

[Before installing, try it live (booted from a DVD disk or USB pendrive)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389),

It will help us help you, if you tell us details about the computer

- Brand name and model
- CPU
- RAM (size)
- internal drive (size)
- graphics chip/card
- wifi chip/card

(You can edit your question to add this information.)